# Distribution of the random variable which counts the number of fixed points of functions on $n$ symbols

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $A_n$ denote the set of all functions from $\{1,...,n\}$ to itself and for $f\in A_n$, let $X_n(f)$ denote the number of fixed points of $f$. Then is it true that $P(X_n=k)={n \choose k}\big(\dfrac 1 n\big)^k \big(1- \dfrac 1 n\big)^{n-k} $ ? i.e. is it true that $X_n $ follows Binomial $(n, \dfrac 1n)$ ?

NOTE: I am equipping $A_n$ with uniform counting measure i.e. for a subset $S$ of $A_n$ the measure of $S$ is $|S|/n^n$ .

Comment: Why do you think this is the result?  How did you come to it?

Comment: Functions or bijective functions (permutations)? I.e. is $|A_n|=n^n$ or $n!$? If the former then you seem to be correct, while if the latter then you may be thinking of [rencontres numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers).

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is a fixed point for a function defined on a discrete set?

Comment: @Henry: not permutations, just functions ... $|A_n|=n^n$ ...

Comment: @herb steinberg
: a fixed point of a function $f: X\to X$  is just $x \in X$ with $f(x)=x$ ... the definition  itself has nothing to do with topology ...

Comment: In that case, what is the range of values for function in $A_n$?  It looks like it is the same as the domain.  If so, you should say so.

Comment: Take $n=2$. Here there are no functions $f:\{1,2\}\rightarrow \{1,2\}$ which has only one fixed point. Also in order to speak of the distribution of $X_n$ you must first specify a probability measure on $\mathcal{A}$, although i assume you are considering a uniform measure (all functions being equally likely).

Comment: @Leander Tilsted Kristensen : sure there is a function with one fixed point ... $f(1)=1=f(2)$ ... I'm not assuming my functions to be injective or surjective or anything ...

Comment: Ah sorry my bad. In that case i think you are correct, we can look at $X_n$ as a sum $Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n$, where $Y_k(f)=1$ if $f(k)=k$ and $0$ otherwise. Clearly $Y_k$ is $Bernoulli(1/n)$ and if we argue that these are independent, then it follows that $X_n$ is $Binom(n,1/n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the number of fixed points of $f$ is distributed like $\text{Bin}(n,1/n)$. Since $f$ is uniformly distributed over $A_n$, it follows the values $f(1),f(2),\dots,f(n)$ are independent, so the number of $f(k)$ which are equal to $k$ will follow a binomial distribution.